# Python 3.x: Ensure a string is ready for printing

Tags: python, encoding

This is something that drove me crazy today while writing large amounts of text to files or stdout. I would often get error messages about bad characters. Here's a simplified test case:

```
Python 3.4.0b2 (v3.4.0b2:ba32913eb13e, Jan  5 2014, 16:13:26) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x='\x92'
>>> print(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x92' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have a big chunk of text. I want to print it all or save to file, but without getting this bug. Is it possible? My preferred solution would be to save this annoying character (are there more?) to file, but if there's a nice way to filter it, that'll be nice too (I know how to filter a single character,but I don't know whether `'\x92'` has a bunch of similar characters to it that also need to be filtered.)

Comment: The code snippet above returns no error in Python 3.3.3. Perhaps it is a configuration problem or a bug in Python 3.4.0

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: Is your console set to CP437?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams no, my console is set to UTF8. Perhaps the problem lies there.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: Indeed. This error only manifests itself when you attempt to print characters that cannot be encoded into the console's character set.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `codecs.StreamWriter` around `sys.stdout` that uses the `backslashreplace` error handler and pass that as the `file` argument of `print()`.

Comment: I don't know how to use the `backslashreplace` error handler.

Comment: Erm, you pass it to the `StreamWriter` constructor, just like the docs say.

Comment: And what do I do with the `StreamWriter` I create? What do you mean have it "around" `sys.stdout`? Sorry I'm not smart enough to complete your thoughts.